# Valores unicos en array bidimensional

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array que utilizo para generar un select option

```
  var values = [['ENERO','LEGAJO','Vacaciones'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Vacaciones'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Enfermedad'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Enfermedad'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Horas Normales (j+)'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Vacaciones'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Enfermedad']];
```

y necesito obtener solamente los valores de la columna 2 unicos es decir.

```
  var values = [['ENERO','LEGAJO','Vacaciones'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Enfermedad'],
    ['ENERO','LEGAJO','Horas Normales (j+)']];
```

Probe utilizar un ciclo for con una variable para comparar, y agregarlos al select

```
function AgregarCat(){

 var Cat = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {          
          if(values[i][2] != Cat){
             $("#select-categoria").append(new Option(values[i][2], values[i][2]));
             Cat = values[i][2];
          }
         }
}
```

Pero al repetirse las variables de categoria, se vuelven a añadir al select.

Comment: Puedes mostrar código? Pregunto porque el javascript donde tienes la declaración de value es inválido a menos que esté definido en otro lado ENERO, LEGAJO, etc.
Al final son strings?

Comment: Si, el array es mucho mas grande, solo puse un fragmento para mostrar lo que intento realizar. Ahí corregi el codigo son string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de guardar solo el ultimo valor de categoria, guarda todos los ya encontrados

```
function AgregarCat(){

    var Cat = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {          
         if(typeof Cat[values[i][2]] === 'undefined'){
             $("#select-categoria").append(new Option(values[i][2], values[i][2]));
             Cat[values[i][2]] = true;
         }
    }
}
```